# useEffect localStorage loop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state, persistence, use-effect

I'm trying to storage a single state and I cannot do that apparently because of a infinite loop. Could you help me?

[image]

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [rows, setRows] = useState("Inicial State");

  function init() {
    const data = localStorage.getItem("my-list");
    if (data) {
      setRows(JSON.parse(data));
    }
    localStorage.setItem("my-list", JSON.stringify(rows));
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    init();
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setRows("Loaded state!")}>Load!</button>
      <div>{rows}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You call init() every time component re-render. Document how to use `useEffect` here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html. You should only call one time like `componentDidMount` in class component by:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    init();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
      localStorage.setItem("my-list", JSON.stringify(rows));
  }, [rows]);
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll accept the another answer because it seems more clearly for me.

Comment: No problem. Happy to help you :)))

Comment: So kind. Hey, when I press the button F5, I still do not have my storage working as I wanted to. Could you help me?

Comment: Well, I want to store the state "rows" as soon as I could just press F5 in my localhost:3000 and It will stay the state which I changed on the button pressing

Comment: If you want to update localStorage after press button. You should have function handle after updated rows by other useEffect to store it down local storage:

    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem("my-list", JSON.stringify(rows));
    }, [rows]);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221585/discussion-between-viet-dinh-and-daniel-cassiano-chaves).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `useEffect` for initialisation, it needs to have an empty dependency array to make sure it only runs onthe first render, not on every render:

```
 useEffect(() => init(), []);
```

Comment: Thanks! Luke, when I press the button F5, I still do not have my storage working as I wanted to. Could you help me?